# Do we need [base-url] when we have [url]?

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[base-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-url) (91 Questions, 1 Follower) seems to me like it should be made a synonym of [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url).

Comment: `base-url` is a specific tag in a HTML page for a browser to resolve urls from. It is a distinct concept.

Comment: That said, there is [`base-tag`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/base-tag) as well. I foresee a synonym request here.

Comment: Oh, and [`baseurl`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/baseurl)! All for related concepts; requireJS has a parameter from which to resolve relative urls, there's the HTML tag, and various and sundry related functions in web frameworks..

Comment: [tag:baseurl] only needs renaming to [tag:base-url].

Comment: I did a bunch, but ran out of steam for now. About 15 left.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Personally I think all of these tags other than [url] are stupid and need to disappear. (Sorta agreeing with the OP I guess...)

Comment: @BoltClock: having looked over them all I think I agree, actually. `base-tag` has a right to existence, *perhaps*. I wouldn't care less if `base-url` and `baseurl` both went *poof*.

Comment: Ok, [tag:baseurl] is now gone.